# How to determine the number of single and double byte in a string

Tags: xml, xslt

Below example where I need to concatenate two nodes addressLine and cityName which can have values of a japanese characters and others. I need to determine how many single byte and double byte character when I concatenate the two nodes.

```
<Header>
  <addressLine>
    <FreeFormText>村山店</FreeFormText>
  </addressLine>
  <cityName>
    <FreeFormText>南河内郡太子町</FreeFormText>
  </cityName>
</Header>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you thinking about a certain encoding in which some characters are represented by a single byte and other by a double byte? Which encoding is that?

Comment: @Martin Honnen thank you for the quick response, the encoding is UTF-8. Sorry for the confusion, I just need to count how many are JP chars and normal single byte chars.

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0? https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-to-codepoints

Comment: P.S. I believe Japanese characters take **three** bytes to encode in UTF-8. And there are "normal" non-Japanese characters such as `©` or `é` that require more than a single byte.

Comment: Just for completeness: did you ensure that your XML has the processing-instruction `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` at the beginning?